# NSDateFormatter date format for "3/31' 0" date string?

Tags: ios

I am trying to convert `@"3/31' 0"` string to date using `NSDateFormatter`, but none of the formats I have tried can't convert this string to `NSDate`.

I have try different combinations of M, MM, D, DD, Y, YY, YYY, but no luck.

Can someone, please, point me to correct date format.

**Edit:** 
correct format for this string should be `"day/month' year"` but I cant express this using `NSDateFormatter` format specification.

Thanks

Comment: What is the trailing zero intended to represent?

Comment: How can one understand whether the 0 represents 2000 or 2010 (or the years which have 0 trailing)?

Comment: Updated the question - numbers positions meaning added. 2000 - will be represented as 0, 2010 - as 10.

Comment: Why not convert it to a decent date format first yourself? And then try to convert it to a date.

Comment: Arno: its not possible. This is a corner case of more complex date format detection code.

Comment: The string format for `NSDateFormatter` must conform to the format patterns from the Unicode Technical Standard #35 http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns. Your string seems not to conform to that standard.

Comment: @vadian - If you actually read the spec you referenced you would see that there is no significant restriction on "format patterns".  The above format is `@"M/dd\' y"`, close as I can understand what the OP wants.

Comment: @HotLicks - The problem is a single `y` does not automatically add 2000 to the value

Comment: @vadian - yes, single y does not add 2000, but its should at least convert to 0 year.

Comment: @HotLicks - Unfortunately NSDateFormatter return nil using @"M/dd\' y" to convert @"3/31' 0" string.

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible to convert @"3/31' 0" string to date, at least using Georgian calendar, because there is no 0 year in Georgian calendar - [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtHist.html).

I.e. @"3/31' 0" is an invalid date string.

Comment: I read that 'If you do attempt to create a date with year 0, it is instead 1 BC'